# How can I make my bot execute the same action while using different messages?

Tags: python, list, discord.py, startswith

Let's say I have a list.

```
List = ["Hello", "Sup", "Hi", "Yo"]
```

I want my bot to send the same message even if I use any of these words.
If the person says Hello, bot will reply with Hello,
If the user says Hi, bot will reply with Hello,
and so on.

Now, I want to use message.content.startswith for this case, so that if the person types Hello along with other things (for example "Hello bot! Nice to see you.") the bot will still reply. I tried to use message.content, but if I have other words besides the "key" one, the bot won't reply.

I tried

```py
List = ["Hello", "Sup", "Hi", "Yo"]

if message.content.startswith(List):
    await bla bla bla
```

but I got an error saying that the first arg. for startswith cannot be a list.
And so yeah, that's basically it. I tried using the "any" function, but I noticed that's not really what I need (as far as I'm concerned, perhaps it is and I am wrong). But this is basically what I want: the bot to reply with the same thing whether if the person says Hello, Sup, Hi, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if message.content.split()[0] is in List:
#Do something
```

This should work and allows you to change whatever in your list and it still work

You could also use message.split()[0].upper() and make sure every word in the list is fully uppercase so it doesnt matter what case the user enters

Comment: Umm... it tells me invalid syntax (it points at in)-   message.split()[0] is in List:

Comment: @JosuePuente yep sorry forgot to add .content, it should work now message me if otherwise

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!! But I had to remove the is :/ after that it worked perfectly.

Comment: @JosuePuente awesome, could you accept my answer as im needing the reputation thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`str.startswith()` can take a `tuple` as an argument, so you can just do

```
tup = ("Hello", "Sup", "Hi", "Yo",)
if message.content.startswith(tup):
    # do something
```

Answer (score -1):

Best practices suggest using a different variable name than List. That said:

```
if message.split(' ')[0] is in List:
     await bla bla bla
```

will check if the first word of the message is in your list, and if so then execute the rest of your code.

Comment: Thank you!!! Although I had to add .content and delete is, but it worked just fine. Thanks once again (also for explaining what is going on.)

Comment: Really? OP said right above that it worked for him. If you're going to be negative, at least post something helpful to the post along with your criticism.

Comment: @LiamFiddler you right. The code you posted wouldnt work and the OP said he had to add .content (see my example) im putting in a edit to make the code work